# Extract only rows with duplicated strings in tab-delimited table

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a long list of data with 10 tab delimited columns. First two columns are the IDs. I would like to retrieve rows of selected IDs.

I started with renaming the selected IDs, so that each of them prepended with `comp-`. Then I tried to extract the rows with selected IDs present in both column 1 and 2.

file:

```
comp-AA11232.1  GR55896.1
AB55887.1   comp-FR87559.1
comp-AC11232.1  comp-AE55888.1
comp-AC66742.1  comp-AD87559.1
```

Desired output:

```
comp-AC11232.1    comp-AE55888.1
comp-AC66742.1    comp-AD87559.1
```

I was using `sed -n '/comp\-.*\tcomp\-.*/p' file`. The output files were all those that met criteria, but unfortunately some of the rows with same criteria missed out in the output files.

Not sure what is happening here. Any idea? Or is there any better approach with grep/awk/sed in this case?

Comment: Your command is almost correct. Can you provide the input lines for which it was more sfiring? The only loose joint is the absence of ^ in the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '$1 ~/^comp-/ && $2 ~/^comp-/' infile
```

same but pass the pattern from a parameter:

```
awk -F'\t' -v pat='comp-' '$1 ~"^" pat && $2 ~"^" pat' infile
```

or compare as string match and still pass from a parameter:

```
awk -F'\t' -v str='comp-' 'index($1, str)==1 && index($2, str)==1' infile
```

see also [How do I find the text that matches a pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65621325/4023950) for other matching options.

Answer (score 2):

**Perl**

```
perl -MList::MoreUtils=all -F'\t' -lane '
  print if all { /^comp-/ } @F[0,1];
' file
```

---

**sed** GNU version

```
$ sed -n '/^comp-.*\tcomp-/p' file
```